# Data retrieval from database using perl with a foreach

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

```
$dbh_source2 = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=.......;port=......;sid=......",'..........','..........');
foreach $data_line (@raw_data) {
    $SEL = "SELECT arg1,arg2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATA_NAME = '$data_line'";
    $sth = $dbh_source2->prepare($SEL);
    $sth->execute();

    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
        print @row;
        print "\n";
    }
}
END {
    $dbh_source2->disconnect if defined($dbh_source2);
}
```

I am trying to grab several lines of data from a user.  I want to take that data and use it to query a database and grab `ARG1` and `ARG2` `WHERE USER_DATA = $data_line`.

It will not display anything.

Comment: Where are you populating `@raw_data`? The code above is fine, there's no matching rows in the DB.

Comment: The code is not fine if the data comes from a user; it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: To echo @ysth - please use the parameter binding apis instead of interpolating `$data_line` directly into the query. It not only addresses the vulnerability but will actually work if `$data_line` has SQL punctuation in it (while your current code will fail).

Comment: I am populating @raw_data with information that was entered in by the user.  I have then enter in lines of data that will be used to grab other data from the database.  I am able to display @raw_data, but I am not able to display the result of the database query.

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `@raw_data` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick revision which uses SQL placeholders in order to keep [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) from destroying your database.  It may also fix the problem you're currently having, but I haven't seen enough details of your problem yet to be sure.

```
my $dbh_source2 = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=.......;port=......;sid=......",'..........','..........');

my $SEL = "SELECT arg1,arg2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATA_NAME = ?";
my $sth = $dbh_source2->prepare($SEL);

foreach my $data_line (@raw_data) {
    $sth->execute($data_line);

    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
        print @row;
        print "\n";
    }
}
END {
    $dbh_source2->disconnect if defined($dbh_source2);
}
```

Comment: I won't be able to show you the TRUE contents but I can give you another example.

The user will enter data in a line by line format.  Each line is the DATA_NAME part of the SELECT STATEMENT in the code above.  I want to pull data from the database for each line in the text field.

Data Line 1
Data Line 2
Data Line 3

So for example, I want to be able to pull ARG 1 and ARG2 where DATA = 'Data Line #'  and I want to do this for EACH LINE OF THE TEXT.

Comment: I want to be able to set up a SELECT statement for each line of data the user enters

Comment: thank you so much!! It actually did work.  The development database that I was querying was not updated, so I used the production one and it now works great!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
my $dbh_source2 = DBI->connect
("dbi:Oracle:host=.......;port=......;sid=......",'..........','..........');

my $SEL = "SELECT arg1,arg2 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATA_NAME = ?";
my $sth = $dbh_source2->prepare($SEL);

foreach my $data_line (@raw_data) {
    chomp $data_line;
    $sth->execute($data_line);

    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
        print "$data_line\t @row\n";
    }
}
END {
    $dbh_source2->disconnect if defined($dbh_source2);
}
```

The issue I was having was the fact that the development database was not updated with the correct information so some of the items came up blank.  When using the production database with the correct information it worked great!

Thank you all for your help!